# Outlet buried behind cabinet and need to find any suggestions

Tags: kitchens

I went to plug in new disposal and the contractor (who was fired) did not cut it in.  I know it's there cause of photo, but I don't know exactly and do no want a 2 foot hole in brand new kitchen cabinet. I was wondering if anyone has used the Walabot or anything else to find a hidden outlet?

Comment: Was it drywalled over? Or was it installed properly in the drywall and then they placed a cabinet over it?

Comment: should searching for it fail, you could cut out the entire cabinet backing neatly, perhaps 1/2in from the edges using an oscillating saw, and re-install it with some glued quarter round or door stop or other trim.

Comment: What is a "Walabot"?

Comment: @FreeMan https://letmegooglethat.com/?q=Walabot

Answer (score 5):

That photo will be a huge help.

First, recognize that electrical boxes are nearly always mounted to wall studs. Wall studs are nearly always placed at regular intervals -- for example, 16 inches on center. (It's also common that there might be a window in the wall above a sink. This means extra studs in the wall but they're going to be at the edges of the window, which probably is about the same as the edges of the sink base, so these aren't of interest.)

Next, boxes can be nailed to either the left or the right side of a stud. But most people swing a hammer right-handed, so when you have to guess, guess that the box will be nailed to the right side of a stud.

So: how do you make use of this info? Find *other* stud(s) in the same wall and measure from there toward the sink base. If there is no backsplash or if it's a thin material you can use a stud finder. Otherwise, measure from other electrical devices like outlets or switches.

Can you find a stud elsewhere in the wall which, when you measure multiples of 16 inches, indicates the likely location of the outlet in the sink base (or the stud to which it is mounted)? That'll give you a good left-right approximation of its location. As you're measuring make sure you account for the width or half-width of a stud, half-width of the outlet, etc so that you identify the center line of the concealed outlet.

Finally estimate the outlet's elevation above the floor. I don't have a good trick for this, but since you have that photo.. estimate its vertical position relative to the plumbing that comes through the wall. (Is it about one-and-a-half-outlets'-height below the drain pipe, for example?)

Double-check the math, and when you're convinced that you have a good idea of the vertical and horizontal center of the concealed outlet, start cutting. I'd use a utility knife, laminate countertop scoring tool, a rotary tool ("Dremel") with a grinding or sanding attachment, etc. The idea is to get through the wood in a slow, methodical way so that you won't gouge the hidden outlet too badly. When a little bit of it is finally exposed you'll be able to see which direction and how far to enlarge your cut-out. You might also choose other cutting tools to finish the cutout once you have a good idea where the edges are.

If the face of the outlet gets damaged more than you like it's no big deal; that can be replaced with new for a few dollars once the hard work of finding it is finished. If there's a face plate buried back there too you can probably break and remove it in pieces, then raise the outlet and replace the plate with a midway or jumbo size to cover the raw edges of the cabinet.

Comment: Greg, "then raise the outlet", can you confirm that this is code legal? Where are you suggesting the outlet box and receptacle be fastened to?

Comment: @P2000 By "raise" I mean bring the device to the face of the wall/cabinet while leaving the box in its place. It's a common thing to do when a box is set too deeply behind drywall for instance. In a non-combustible surface set-back of the box up to 1/4" into the surface is allowed, but because the cabinet is wood (combustible) a box extension ring would be required to "extend to the surface or project therefrom." (314.20 Flush-Mounted Installations)

Comment: Great Greg, that's an important point you make. I've seen too many questionable standoffs, with receptacles screwed to the cabinet rather than the box, and a gap w/o extension, and just wanted to check it's indeed something we should discourage.

Answer (score 1):

Never tried a Walabot, so I don't know if it would truly be up to the task. Probably depends on the type of cabinet back. I'd be reluctant to buy one just for this task, though it does have a 30-day money-back guarantee.

Two other suggestions:

- Look around the pipes

You should have hot and cold water coming in and sewage going out. The hot & cold might be coming from the wall or from the base. The sewage definitely should be going out through the wall. You may be able to do some poking around the pipes, e.g., using a borescope (I know, another fun tool to buy...) or even poke around with a bent wire hanger. How well this will work depends on the gap between the cabinet back and the wall, which could be anywhere from "nothing" to an inch.

- Cut a nice rectangle

Seriously. Cut a nice even rectangle. A [reciprocating saw would make quick work of this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kv333_yJhWE) if you do it carefully. Careful is important - you *know* there is junction box lurking behind the wall, so you really don't want to cut very deep. **Turn off the breaker for the circuit first, just in case.**